# XSLT count comma values count

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a value like integer="1,2,3,4,5" in the xml. How can I count the total number using XSLT. So that the output gives me a count of 5

Regards,
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way (there may be others). Simply translate all commas into empty strings, and then compare in difference in length of strings:

```
<xsl:value-of 
   select="string-length(@integer) 
           - string-length(translate(@integer, ',', '')) + 1" />
```

If you need to handle empty strings, try this instead

```
<xsl:value-of 
  select="string-length(@integer) 
          - string-length(translate(@integer, ',', '')) 
          + 1 * (string-length(@integer) != 0)" />
```

Comment: This does not work in the trivial case of an empty list. You may need to adjust with a test.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the comma-separated-values, but ALSO be able to reference the individual items, you can use a recursive template like such.

This XSLT 1.0 style-sheet will convert the comma-separated-values into nodes and then count them ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:variable name="as-nodes"> 
  <xsl:call-template name="parse-comma-separated-values">
   <xsl:with-param name="csv" select="t/@csv" />
  </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:value-of select="count(msxsl:node-set($as-nodes)/*)" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="parse-comma-separated-values">
 <xsl:param name="csv" />
 <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="$csv = ''"/>
   <xsl:when test="not( contains( $csv, ','))">
     <value-node value="{$csv}" /> 
   </xsl:when>  
   <xsl:otherwise>
     <value-node value="{substring-before($csv,',')}" /> 
     <xsl:call-template name="parse-comma-separated-values">
      <xsl:with-param name="csv" select="substring-after($csv,',')"/>
     </xsl:call-template>  
   </xsl:otherwise>  
  </xsl:choose>  
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

... when applied to this input document ...

```
 <t csv="1,2,3,4,5"/>
```

... produces ...

```
 5
```